# java.awt.Color changing rgb color after creation

Tags: java, colors

When I create a Color object with java.awt.Color, I can set its color with the constructor, but i don't figure out how to change it after (when my color object is already created).

So is it a way to set again RGB values after construction ? I don't see any setters in the regular class ...

```
Color light_color = new Color(0,0,0);
```

As it seems to be impossible, I need to give a Color object to the setColor function of my Graphics object but i also need to be able to change RGB values. Is it a way to rewrite the class or something to add RGB setters ? i'm beginner in Java ^^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't change it.  A `Color` object is designed to be immutable.  That's why there are no setters.

The same applies to the Java FX `Color` class.